# Stepwise multinomial logistic regression

Tags: r

I'm working on a stepwise multinomial logistic regression in R,
using the `multinom()` function from the `nnet` package and the `stepAIC()` function from `MASS`.
Despite pre-selecting a set of variables using individual logistic regressions (which uses the full parallel potential of the optimized BLAS and LAPACK libraries that I've gotten from the Microsoft R Open installation),
I still have 80+ variables to work with. The problem is the time consumption of performing the aforementioned stepwise multinomial logistic regression.

I've tried the parallel backbend of the caret package, but the stepwise function does not seem to take it as a valid method. I like this package because it lets me perform cross-validation in an easy way.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Here is an example with Iris:

```
> library(nnet)
> library(doParallel)
> library(caret)
> library(MASS)
> 
> data("iris")
> #iris
> 
> Nucleos <- makePSOCKcluster(4)
> registerDoParallel(Nucleos)
> ContEnt <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
> EducRLM <- train(Species ~ ., iris, method = "multinom", trControl = ContEnt, allowParallel = TRUE)
# weights:  18 (10 variable)
initial  value 164.791843 
iter  10 value 16.214880
iter  20 value 7.193408
iter  30 value 6.317798
iter  40 value 6.165829
iter  50 value 6.154233
iter  60 value 6.149611
iter  70 value 6.148398
iter  80 value 6.147275
final  value 6.147102 
converged
> 
> stepAIC(EducRLM, direction = "both")
```

> ```
> Error in UseMethod("extractAIC") : 
>   no applicable method for 'extractAIC' applied to an object of class "c('train', 'train.formula')"
> In addition: Warning message:
> In nobs.default(object, use.fallback = TRUE) :
>   no 'nobs' method is available
> >
> ```

Comment: Last answer looks like it may help you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355217/stepwise-regression-with-multinomial-logit-models-in-r

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was because `stepAIC()` apparently doesn't work with the models from `train()`so when I tried with `lm()`(I wanted a simple regression) it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the train data back to a linear model: `stepAIC(lm(EducRLM,data=iris),direction="both")`

If this comes back with the same error, make sure the data is in a dataframe class and try the above again.